# Regression: Should ordinal variables start at 1 or 0?

Tags: regression, ordinal-data

I have a multiple regression that contains multiple variables, many of them ordinal with 3 or 4 possible choices. (e.g: *Are you currently experiencing stress? 1: No, not at all. 2: Somewhat. 3: Yes, quite a lot.*)

My question is a follows - should I start these variables at 1, 0 or doesn't it matter? The advantage of starting at 0 is that the intercept of the regression has more meaning (e.g, the base value at the *absence* of all other factors) - but starting at 1 is easier for people at questionnaires.

Comment: If it matters in the regression, you are treating the variable as interval-scaled and not just ordinal.

Comment: This question is founded on a misconception: numbers like $0, 1,$ etc are merely *codes* used to indicate the sequence of values an ordinal variable.  You may freely replace them by any other sequence of numbers that preserve the order, such as $-10^6, 0.1, \pi$ instead of $1,2,3.$ Recognizing this fact will create opportunities for deeper and more useful analysis, because it shows that you are free to select these numerical codes in *any* order-preserving manner that helps with understanding or prediction.

Comment: Start at 1 in questionnaires and transform to start at 0 for the regression.

Comment: @whuber - thanks for your response! If I understand correctly I will still have to increment the effect with the position of the code in the sequence right? For example, if the sequence is [ -10, 4, 340 ], and the regression show that the increase of each step is 0.5. A value of '4' would correspond to '2x --> 2 * 0.5'?

Comment: @whuber I would appreciate if you could expand on your answer or provide a resource on why it doesn't matter how the categories are encoded as long as they're in order. Thanks!

Comment: @afarrag This is the definition. Any *measurement scale* assigns numbers to observations. So, abstractly, it is a function $t:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ where $\Omega$ is the set of things that potentially could be measured. A measurement scale is *ordinal* when the composition $p\circ t$ is for every purpose equivalent to $t$ *provided* $p$ is strictly increasing. Indeed, any analysis of data $(x_i)$ of an ordinal measurement type *must* yield the same conclusions when applied to the transformed data $(p(x_i))$ for any such $p.$ See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_measurement.